# What ProxyCommand to use for ssh host-based authentication relay?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a host $HOST which I can (only) access by `ssh`ing to a host $BASTION and then, by *host-based authentication*, connect to with `ssh $HOST`.  $HOST does not accept access by for example public-key authentication.

What `ProxyCommand` do I need to configure so that on my local machine `ssh $HOST` connects me transparently to $HOST?

I use OpenSSH 6.2p2 on my local machine and OpenSSH 5.9p1 on $BASTION and $HOST.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ssh in "stdio forward" mode. This causes ssh to connect to the specified host and request that sshd open an forwarded connection to another host. The ssh client will connect this fowarded connection to stdin/out, which makes it nice to use as a ProxyCommand.

An example ssh_config snippet:

```
Host behind-bastion
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion
```

Note that hostbased authentication can be pretty finicky about matching the DNS name for the address of an incoming connection with the name associated with the public key in /etc/ssh/known_hosts. If you run into problems here, you might need to set HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly=yes in $HOST's sshd_config.